# How to create a plugin in JMeter

Tags: plugins, jmeter

i would like to create a JMeter plugin. I would like to understand how to write and pack my code to extend JMeter with my Sample. More in detail i'm looking for an "adhoc" TCPSampler that implement my protocol.
I tried following an old pdf document from JMeter site but it doesn't work. Where is the mistake? 
Can you help me with some examples?

Thank you
RM

Answer (score 7):

There are several options to extend JMeter.

1. Use JSR223 Sampler (groovy language is recommended to use as it can be compiled into Java code, however you'll need to d[ownload groovy-all.jar](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download) and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Use [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - basically the same, but it's built-in. Have lower performance than JSR223 + Groovy
3. Create your own Java Request. 2 Java Request samplers are shipped with JMeter - [JavaTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/doc-v2_3_1/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java) and [SleepTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/doc-v2_3_1/src/protocol/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java). You can inspect their source to see how they're implemented.
4. Create your own Sampler. See [ExampleSampler](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/doc-v2_3_1/src/examples/org/apache/jmeter/examples/sampler/ExampleSampler.java) source code for details and how to implement it or even use it as a base for your plugin.

All JMeter Extensions should be packaged as .jar and live under /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation.

Comment: Are you sure answer is related to question ?

Comment: Apologies, initially provided answer should go to another place, corrected this one.

Comment: Do i need also other files (like Beans or .properties) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is book - How to Write a plugin for JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf

Comment: The book is quite old - created in 2005, never updated. [Developer manual](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/DeveloperManual) is slightly better, since it was updated in 2011. However sample code (as suggested by Dmitri T) is really the best option.